# Capturing all occurrences of interleavened nodes with StandardTokenParsers in Scala

Tags: parsing, scala

I'm learning how to use Parsers in Scala, and I'm trying to build a parser (extending from StandardTokenParsers) for a text file that can have occurrences of the same node type with other node types in between. For example:

[NodeA]
...

[Node B]
...

[Node A]
...

[Node A]
...

[Node A]
...

How can I capture all instances of Node A and store them on a collection? I think repsep can only capture sequential instances.

At the end, I want to be able to store all instances of Nodes in different collections.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a parser that accept a sequence of either [NodeA] or [NodeB].
All you need, given a parser `nodeAParser` and a parser `nodeBParser`, is use the `|` combinator to parse for either [NodeA] or [NodeB] ( `nodeAParser | nodeBParser` ), and then use combinator `*` to accept a sequence of that ( `(nodeAParser | nodeBParser).*` ).

Some dummy example:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.input._
abstract sealed class Node
case object NodeA extends Node
case object NodeB extends Node

object MyParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters ++= Seq("[", "]")
  lexical.reserved ++= Seq("NodeA", "NodeB")
  lazy val nodeAP: Parser[Node] = "[" ~ "NodeA" ~ "]" ^^ { case _ => NodeA }
  lazy val nodeBP: Parser[Node] = "[" ~ "NodeB" ~ "]" ^^ { case _ => NodeB }
  lazy val nodesP: Parser[List[Node]] = phrase((nodeAP | nodeBP).*)
  def parse( s: String ) = { nodesP( new lexical.Scanner( s ) ) }
}

MyParser.parse(
"""
[NodeA]
[NodeB]
[NodeA]
[NodeA]
[NodeA]
"""
)
```

Comment: yeap. I can process the created list afterwards